# Create and Append a .csv with Each round of a loop

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

So I'm having trouble appending the data to a csv with a functioning `foreach loop.`

I've created static `CSV's` before but the fact that I'm redefining the variable has me going crazy. Here's what I have for my code:

```
[long]$IntSent=0
[long]$IntRec=0
[long]$IntTotal=0
$startdate="02/01/2018 00:00:01"

$domains=@("aaa.com","bbb.com","ccc.com")
$users=@("user1","user2","user3")



ForEach ($user in $users) {
    foreach ($domain in $domains) {
        get-messagetrackinglog -start $startdate  -Recipient $user -resultsize unlimited -EventID Receive | where {[string]$_.sender -like "*@$domain"} |ForEach{$IntRec++}
        #|Where {[String]$_.recipients -notlike "*@belamiecommerce.com*"}

        write-host ($domain, $user , $intrec)
        #Write-host ($IntRec)
        #$IntTotal=$IntSent + $IntRec
        #write-host ($IntTotal)
        [long]$IntRec = 0
    }
}
```

I'd like to get the output in the following format

```
aaa.com, user1, value
bbb.com, user1, value
ccc.com, user1, value
aaa.com, user2, value
bbb.com, user2, value
```

etc.

Any idea on how I create the file at the top of the script, then append like crazy, then output?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have converted your `foreach` loops to a `ForEach-Object` pipeline. It's a lot easier to work with.

Also all your temp variables and counting/incrementing does not seem necessary. Powershell is perfectly able to `.Count` things for you.

Since you need to query the log only once per user, let's move the `Get-MessageTrackingLog` out of the inner loop to save some time. Look into the documentation if `Get-MessageTrackingLog` actually accepts more than one `-Recipient`, you might be able to move that out of the loop entirely.

Arrays in PowerShell can be defined easily by just writing a few comma-separated values. `@()` is not necessary here.

Creating `[pscustomobject]`s in the inner loop makes Powershell print a nice table, and they are compatible to `ConvertTo-CSV` cmdlet. Note that any value you create inside a `{block}` will become part of that block's return value. That's how the below script creates its `$result`.

```
$startdate="02/01/2018 00:00:01"
$domains="aaa.com","bbb.com","ccc.com"
$users="user1","user2","user3"

$result = $users | ForEach-Object {
    $user = $_
    $log = Get-MessageTrackingLog -start $startdate -Recipient $user -resultsize unlimited -EventID Receive
    $domains | ForEach-Object {
        $domain = $_
        [pscustomobject]@{
            domain = $domain
            user = $user
            messages = ($log | Where-Object sender -like "*@$domain").Count
        }
    }
}

# output $result to screen...
$result

# ...or output it to a file
$result | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File "mesages.csv" -Encoding utf8
```

Using `Where-Object { $_.sender.ToString().EndsWith("@$domain") }` might turn out to be faster than `-like "*@$domain"`.

Comment: I'm fairly new to powershell (I tried to swear off coding for as long as possible as an IT guy) 

Given that, I understand about 35% of what you said. 

However, I'm pretty sure I love you.

Comment: Does it work? I have no way to test it beyond "looks reasonable" and "does not throw syntax errors"

Comment: I mean, I'm running it now. It seems to be doing a lookup on my exchange server for every foreach-object round. So... probably? Will report back. I have quite a few users (10) and domains (9) and the lookups are taking about 2.5 minutes a piece (just like mine did) so it'll be a hot minute.

Comment: Looks like I have some 0's AND some nulls. This worries me. Thoughts? https://i.imgur.com/A3HMSuC.png

Comment: I guess `$null` occurs when there are no log entries for this user *at all*, and `0` when there are some for the user, but not with this domain. It has to do with whether `Get-MessageTrackingLog` returned something to begin with or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but it should get you started.

Create an arraylist before the loop starts, add your output from each iteration of the loop into the array and export the array to a csv file after the loop.

```
[long]$IntSent=0
[long]$IntRec=0
[long]$IntTotal=0
$startdate="02/01/2018 00:00:01"

$domains=@("aaa.com","bbb.com","ccc.com")
$users=@("user1","user2","user3")
$Arr = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList


ForEach ($user in $users) 
{
    foreach ($domain in $domains) 
    {
        get-messagetrackinglog -start $startdate  -Recipient $user -resultsize unlimited -EventID Receive | where {[string]$_.sender -like "*@$domain"}|ForEach{[void]$Arr.Add($_)}
    }
}

$Arr | Export-Csv -Path C:\file
```

Or Create a function, call it back and pipe it into Export-Csv

```
[long]$IntSent=0
[long]$IntRec=0
[long]$IntTotal=0
$startdate="02/01/2018 00:00:01"

$domains=@("aaa.com","bbb.com","ccc.com")
$users=@("user1","user2","user3")

function do-task
{
    param
    (
        [string[]]$Users,
        [String[]]$Domains
    )

    ForEach ($user in $users) 
    {
        foreach ($domain in $domains) 
        {
            get-messagetrackinglog -start $startdate  -Recipient $user -resultsize unlimited -EventID Receive | where {[string]$_.sender -like "*@$domain"}|ForEach{[void]$Arr.Add($_)}
        }
    }
}

do-task -User $users -Domains $domains | Export-Csv -Path c:\file
```

Comment: These are a little advanced for me but I think I'm going to play around with the array list. Thanks sir!